# Android - RecyclerView StaggeredGridLayoutManager stretch width of last row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I use RecyclerView  with StaggeredGridLayoutManager spanCount 3

the problem is if the number of element not 3 or 6 or 9
the last row not stretch to parent

[image]

**But I want this(photoshoped) :**

[image]

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recv.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);



.
.
.
public adap.vh onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) viewGroup.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final ImageView imgx = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imggalview, viewGroup, false);
            return new vh(imgx);
        }
.
.
.
```

**imggalview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bob"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved using **[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)**. So it has a property to set the span size. By default, each item occupies 1 span. You can change it by providing a custom **GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup** instance via **setSpanSizeLookup(SpanSizeLookup)**.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: good but not helped me , because cannot place two columns side by side if spanCount is 3 because  spanSize is fixed int and cannot be 1.5f !